# Single transaction, multiple service calls to Entity Framework updating database

Tags: sql-server, entity-framework-core, transactions

I have a case with a single database defined by a single Entity Framework DbContext.

I have things set up where updating the database is via services. This separates things out nicely and makes it easy to mock the database for the bUnit (Blazor server app) tests.

But I need to accomplish the following:

1. Start transaction
2. Call PlaceOrder service
3. Call UpdateInventory service
4. Complete transaction

How can I accomplish this in a way where the outer code does not explicitly use Entity Framework (so I can mock in unit tests)?

The best I've come up with is create `MyDbContext` and pass that in to each. That works but it feels awkward. I am SQL Server (dev) and Azure SQL Database (production) so a solution that requires SQL Server works for me.

Comment: Are you looking for a "Unit Of Work" approach? e.g. https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/mvc/overview/older-versions/getting-started-with-ef-5-using-mvc-4/implementing-the-repository-and-unit-of-work-patterns-in-an-asp-net-mvc-application

Comment: @DaleK That looks like a good approach. Question, Do you think the UoW object should have the entitiy services as properties? Or that the repositor service for each entity is passed the UoW? And if you write this all up as an answer, happy to select it. TIA

Comment: I can't remember, it's been a long time since I implemented a UOW pattern from scratch. But a quick internet search will find you many examples to study.

Comment: @DaleK yes it does - and it's about 50/50 between the two approaches. I think either will work well, but if you write an answer, please speak to this. TIA.